# f-string formatting with only constant expressions?

Tags: python, f-string

I'm trying to learn Python from the book: "[Fluent Python, 2nd Ed](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fluent-python-2nd/9781492056348/)" by Luciano Ramalho.

**Example 2-8. Unpacking nested tuples to access the longitude**

```
metro_areas = [
    ('Tokyo', 'JP', 36.933, (35.689722, 139.691667)),  
    ('Delhi NCR', 'IN', 21.935, (28.613889, 77.208889)),
    ('Mexico City', 'MX', 20.142, (19.433333, -99.133333)),
    ('New York-Newark', 'US', 20.104, (40.808611, -74.020386)),
    ('São Paulo', 'BR', 19.649, (-23.547778, -46.635833)),
]

def main():
    print(f'{"":15} | {"latitude":>9} | {"longitude":>9}')
    for name, _, _, (lat, lon) in metro_areas:
        if lon <= 0:
            print(f'{name:15} | {lat:9.4f} | {lon:9.4f}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here in `print(f'{"":15} | {"latitude":>9} | {"longitude":>9}')` I can't understand logic behind using `{"":15}, {"latitude":>9, {"longitude":>9}` part of the code. Can anyone can explain why the writer uses this in a `print()` function call?

The output:

```
                |   lat.    |   lon.
Mexico City     |   19.4333 |  -99.1333
New York-Newark |   40.8086 |  -74.0204
São Paulo       |  -23.5478 |  -46.6358
```

Comment: Your question is about string formatting in that `print()` call, but your title indicates that you have a question about tuple unpacking. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Titles are supposed to summarize the question

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: `{"":15}, {"latitude":>9, {"longitude":>9}` formats the column headings in fields of the specified width, so that they match the widths of the data rows.

Comment: Title edited, If that was not upto standard, im learning how to ask question thanks for suggesting @PranavHosangadi

Comment: It's just a so-called "f-string" or [formatted string litera](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) where all the replacement fields are expressions that involves only string constants and no variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is to print the table header with the same field widths as the actual table, so that they line up. Compare these lines:

```
print(f'{"":15} | {"latitude":>9} | {"longitude":>9}')
print(f'{name:15} | {lat:9.4f} | {lon:9.4f}')
```

Instead of variables (`name`, `lat`, `lon`), the author is passing literal strings (`""`, `"latitude"`, `"longitude"`) to the f-string format arguments instead. This is valid, because the part between `{}` can be any valid expression.

By using the same field widths (`15`, `9`, `9`) in both statements, the code ensures that the column headings have the same width as the actual table cells, so they are aligned in the output.

Comment: Ah got it ... Thanks Thomas for explaining it. @Thomas

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(f'{"":15} | {"latitude":>9} | {"longitude":>9}')
```

Here the author is just formatting the values nicely to human readers. He's using what's knowns as f-strings which is used to interpolate strings.

You can place expressions inside curly braces of strings prefixed with an `f`, as in this case.

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

The colon is used to apply a format specifier to the expression. In this case, the specifier `>` "Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space", and the number 9 is the width for that specifier.

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language